# How to create two different users(doctor and patient) using Abstractuser class in Django so that both of them can perform their own role

Tags: python, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I want to create two users with these details.

```py
class Doctor(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    gender = models.CharField(choices=GENDER_CHOICES, max_length=128)
    specialties = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    education = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    hospitals = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    rate = models.FloatField()
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True)
```

```py
class Patient(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    gender = models.CharField(choices=GENDER_CHOICES, max_length=128)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm starting to use this approach either, and judging for the time your question have here, it is very probable that you already figured this out, but I want to answer this since I was looking for an answer not that long ago, and maybe this could help others.

Anyway, I was previously using the 'profile like' way before this AbstractUser one, but in your answer I see them both mixed, in your patient model you're using a OneToOne FK to the original auth_user model, but you're asking for the AbstractUser.
So just in case you're looking for the 'Profile like' which is really called 'proxy model' option, you're already almost done, you would just need to add a OneToOne field to the User as in your Patient model but in the Doctor model, and then you would have two models with extra information, but nothing to do with login, access or permissions, just for profile, ready to go.
The docs on the following link explain this
[Proxy model basic documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model)

Now if what you're looking for is to use the other way, substituting the user model, for which you need the AbstractUser, what you need to do (or better stated, what you could do, which is what I'm doing now) is to create a base custom user class.
Which you can see a full example in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example)
In your case

```
class MyBaseUser(AbstractUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    gender = models.CharField(choices=GENDER_CHOICES, max_length=128)


class Doctor(MyBaseUser):
    specialties = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    education = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    hospitals = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    rate = models.FloatField()
    description = models.TextField(null=True)

class Patient(MyBaseUser):
    age = models.IntegerField()
```

Now, remember that you need to specify in the settings the AUTH_USER_MODEL, you could follow a cookiecutter template so all of this would be pre-formatted.
Also, you can add your USERNAME_FIELD within your MyBaseUser class to state which field would be used as login username, as well as the REQUIRED_FIELDS in the same class.

Have a nice one, as our friend Destin likes to say.